# Azure SQL DB-Securing communication on Port 1433

Tags: sql, azure

I am using Azure SQL Server DB and need to connect to it through my local development environment since we do not have local Db setup. I am using Entity Framework and standard connection string to connect over port 1433. This requires port 1433 opened in organizations firewall.

However, the security group in my workplace wants me to ensure that this communication is secured, to protest data exposure, so that they can open the port 1433 for my work.

How do i ensure that? If this is secured by default, then some link that explains it. If not, the steps I can take to make it happen.

Or point me to a question where this is resolved. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. An Azure Database connection already enforces SSL/TLS. Anything else (e.g. inbound/outbound traffic control) would need to be discussed with your networking team.

Answer (score 3):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview:

> #### Important
>
> **All connections to Azure SQL Database require encryption (SSL/TLS) at all times while data is "in transit" to and from the database.** In your application's connection string, you must specify parameters to encrypt the connection and not to trust the server certificate (this is done for you if you copy your connection string out of the Azure Classic Portal), otherwise the connection will not verify the identity of the server and will be susceptible to "man-in-the-middle" attacks. For the ADO.NET driver, for instance, these connection string parameters are `Encrypt=True` and `TrustServerCertificate=False`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.